# ORA-00906 - missing left parenthesis

Tags: oracle

I don't see any missing left parenthesis but I keep seeing the error.

```
CREATE TABLE OWNER
(owner_id NUMBER(30),
CONSTRAINT owner_id_pk
PRIMARY KEY,
owner_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: try having the statement between parenthesis on one line

Comment: @VictorSmt: why would that make a difference?  SQL is free format; you can interchange blanks and newlines pretty freely (outside strings).

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE OWNER
(owner_id NUMBER(30)  --<---- without comma
CONSTRAINT owner_id_pk
PRIMARY KEY,
owner_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Does adding the comma shown in the question trigger the error message?  I 100% agree that the comma isn't wanted because with the comma present, the 'constraint clause' is not associated with a specific column so you'd need to write `CONSTRAINT owner_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(owner_id),` to specify which column(s) are the primary key and, lo and behold, there's a left parenthesis missing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: that syntax is fine. It's a named inline constraint a "longer" version of `owner_id number primary key`